# How to display or redirect to Community User's Contact detail?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, landing-page

Is it possible to have a visual force page load a different record based on the User who is going to that Visual force page? So I am working with Communities on this one, and I want the users to login and be sent directly to their own contact record. Their Contact record is listed on the user record. So I was thinking that I could maybe put in a redirect and then look at that field and do a page reload and just merge in that id to send them to the right record. But I have just been spinning for a while I can't seem to figure out which way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to show the detail page, then you could use the `<apex:detail>` component:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:detail subject="{!$User.ContactId}" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL($User.ContactId))}" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Adrian, One final thing. I think I want to change this up to have the page that is loaded be that Contact's Account. I Changed the merge field to be this `{!$User.Contact.AccountId}` which I verified that relationship name and field name in workbench and it is saying `Error: Could not access the following field: Contact.AccountId. Contact your administrator`

Comment: Might be a permissions issue. Sounds like a separate question, honestly. Though I'm sure there are some Q&A posts around here that address accessing `AccountId` as a community user.

Comment: I don't see how it would be a permission issue. I am getting the error while making the visual force page, not when the user logs in.

Comment: @cmmoutes13 You might need to add a controller/extension to get the `AccountId` value. Probably can't pull cross-object data from the `$User` global variable.

Comment: Yeah, I thought maybe I could also work around this by bringing the Account Id down to a field on the User using a formula field. And that lets me save it, but then when the community user logs in they don't get redirected to it properly so idk

Comment: Also, will I be able to modify this at all? I want to be able to work with the layout and styling for this visualforce page and I don't think I can since I am just throwing it in through detail

Comment: @cmmoutes13 You can access this value via `Apex`, roll your own controller, and build basically anything you want.